# My desktop background is not the color black

Tags: gnome-shell

[image: Desktop:Color:Black]

I've set the desktop background to be the color black. This is not a black desktop background. Why is this? This is on an 18.04 fresh install.

For those of you that cant see the fault: I mucked around in gimp with a section and applied Color->Threshold and got

[image]

With a black image the problem disappears.

[image: Black image]

Comment: Perhaps this is a hardware problem? Can you do a google search or something similar for plain black images? Does that look any different? The screenshot appears to be black on my end.

Comment: It's true that your first background is #050505 instead of #0000. Where did you select it? On 18.04 [the black color from settings is a pure black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtfWt.png).

Comment: @PabloBianchi That was the selector i used.